# R - Dynamic Variable Names and Nested Loop

Tags: r, loops, dynamic-programming

I need to run a piece of code 15 times.

```
# Number of Successes for y rolls -- rolls = 1
Num.Dice <- 1 # number of dice
x <- 1 # Initialize While Loop
a1 <- c() # create empty vector
while(x < 100000) {
  a1[(x:x)] <- sum(sample(1:6, Num.Dice, replace=TRUE)>=5)
  x <- x + 1
}

# Number of Successes for y rolls -- rolls = 2
Num.Dice <- 2 # number of dice
x <- 1 # Initialize While Loop
a2 <- c() # create empty vector
while(x < 100000) {
  a2[(x:x)] <- sum(sample(1:6, Num.Dice, replace=TRUE)>=5) # load number of dice above 5/6
  x <- x + 1 # step loop
}

...
```

This will create 15 separate vectors a1:a15. A monte carlo simulation (100000 repetitions) models the number of dice (Num.Dice) above a five or six for each.  The number of dice in each roll increases with each vector (1-15 :: a1:15 -> example provides code for linear programming of a1 and a2).

I would like to use a loop to do this with a dynamic variable name for each vector.  Between the loop and the dynamic variable name I don't know where to start.

Comment: Unless you need the variables `a1` to `a15` to exist in your global environment, you should probably hold them in a list `lapply(1:15, function(n_dice){sapply(1:100000, function(iteration){sum(sample(1:6, n_dice, replace = TRUE)>=5)})})`. Otherwise you could use the `assign` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure this is what you have in mind, but the code below returns a `data.frame` called `final_df` which contains all your sampled vectors in columns.

Everything is done in base R. Please, not that the while loop goes up to 10 for readability. Change that accordingly.

Please have a look if this is what you want.

```r
# number of runs
Nruns <- 15

# output structure as a list for convenience
out_structure <- vector( "list", Nruns )

for ( i_dice in seq_len( Nruns ) ) {
  # Number of Successes for y rolls -- rolls = 1
  Num.Dice <- i_dice # number of dice
  x <- 1 # Initialize While Loop
  a <- c() # create empty vector
  while(x < 10) {
    # this temporary saves the vector "a" in each run
    a[(x:x)] <- sum(sample(1:6, i_dice, replace=TRUE)>=5)
    x <- x + 1
  }
  # and then assigns it to the output structure
  out_structure[[i_dice]] <- a
}

# convert everything in a data.frame for dicing and slicing
final_df <- as.data.frame(out_structure, 
                          col.names = paste0("a", seq_len( Nruns )))
final_df
#>   a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a15
#> 1  0  1  3  1  2  2  0  3  4   3   6   1   5   2   6
#> 2  0  0  1  1  1  4  3  3  5   0   5   4   4   5   3
#> 3  1  0  1  1  2  2  2  2  4   5   4   5   7   4   7
#> 4  0  0  1  1  4  0  3  3  2   4   4   3   2   6   4
#> 5  0  1  1  0  0  1  3  1  3   3   3   4   4   7   3
#> 6  0  0  2  2  1  1  3  2  5   3   5   7   6   6   6
#> 7  0  0  2  2  3  3  2  4  2   1   3   5   5   5   4
#> 8  0  1  1  2  0  2  3  1  2   5   6   6   3   8   4
#> 9  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  1  3   5   2   5   5   5   6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I really like this answer. It gives me multiple ways to improve my code!!!